# What does the T in RVR-T stand for?

Tags: faa, aeronautical-charts, chart-supplement

In the [Chart Supplement (A/FD) for CRQ/KCRQ](https://skyvector.com/files/tpp/1608/afdpdf/sw_99_21jul2016.pdf), you will find RVR-T for runway 24.

I was wondering what 'T' stands for?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From page 5-1-7, contractions in the [AIM](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/aim.pdf):

> RVRT . . . . . . . . . RVR Touchdown

The full list is:

> RVR . . . . . . . . . . Runway Visual Range
>   RVRM . . . . . . . .  RVR Midpoint
>   RVRR . . . . . . . . . RVR Rollout
>   RVRT . . . . . . . . . RVR Touchdown

On some runways there are multiple RVR sensors and different points along the runway, and these are the names given to identify the different locations.

Answer (score 6):

Runway Visual Range - Touchdown

From [FAA 6560.10C](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/6560.10C.pdf)

> Touchdown RVR VSs are located 0 feet to 2,500 feet (0 meters to 750 meters) from the runway threshold, normally behind the instrument landing system (ILS) glide slope (G/S) antenna, precision approach path indicator (PAPI), visual approach slope indicator (VASI), or microwave landing system (MLS) elevation antenna (if applicable).

Answer (score 3):

While the other answers are correct, the dash in RVR-T is missing.

An overhaul (Interagency Air Cartographic Committee) done to the AFD makes it hard to get the up-to-date legend unless you're willing to download the full **[300 MB document](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dafd/)**.

But I managed to find **just** the guidelines: [Chart Supplement IACC 8](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/iacc/media/IACC8/IACC-8-25APR2016-complete.pdf), dated 25 April 2016.

> 3.1.5.3.13.11
>
> Runway Visual Range shall be shown as RVR appended with T for touchdown, M for midpoint, and R for rollout; e.g., RVR-TMR.

It's got the dash!

Comment: Haha, just like them to have two different ways of saying the same thing!

Comment: I came across `RVR-TMR` on the Chart Supplement of KMHR. Thanks for digging this information!